# tkinter scroll multiple widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm having some trouble with some code, I want to scroll a group of widgets on a screen, but the scroll bar isn't working right. I have attached a picture of the result and some code bellow, I'm using python tkinter, namesfile.txt just contains a list of people.

```
tkinter import *


Y_level=10

people = []

f = open("namefile.txt", "r")
for people_in_file in f:
    people.append(people_in_file)

parent = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(parent)
scroll_y = Scrollbar(parent, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

frame = Frame(canvas)

for person in people:
    label_name='person: '+person    
    print(label_name)
    print(Y_level)
    
    
    label_name = Label(parent, text=person)
    label_name.place(x=10, y=Y_level)
    Y_level=Y_level+20

canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=frame)

canvas.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'), 
                 yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
scroll_y.pack(fill='y', side='right')
    
parent.mainloop()
```

[Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZclg.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what the scroll bar is doing that it shouldn't be doing, or what it's not doing that you expect it to be doing.  I can't tell that from the picture and code.

Answer (score 0):

First you should put the labels inside `frame` instead of `parent`.  Second you should use `pack()` instead of `place()` because `place()` will not expand the parent container.

```
for person in people:
    label_name='person: '+person    
    print(label_name)
    label_name = Label(frame, text=person)
    label_name.pack()
```